# Emulate on coordinate click on coordinates js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have wrap element button. In wrap insert fasebook follow button and "holder"(this block overlap wrapper and catch event for piwik). I want hide holder on mousedown and emulate mousedown in page coordinate grid to generate click in fasebook follow button. But in generate event mousedown "x" and "y" position undefinded.

Listener :

```js
        jQuery(document).on("mousedown", ".wrap", function(e){
                    console.info(e,e.pageX+"!!!!!!!!!!mousedown");
                    jQuery(this).find(".holder").css({display:"none"});
                    jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(parseInt(e.pageX), parseInt(e.pageY))).mousedown();
                });
```

```css
    .wrap{
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #5896A6;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

     .wrap .holder{
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap"> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/uk_UA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=232725503584949&version=v2.3";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="button" data-show-faces="true"></div>

    <div class="holder"></div> <!--*холдер который перекрывает кнопку-->
</div>
```

How I can fix it????

Comment: why would anyone need this? what for?

Comment: I need track in "piwik" click on facebook follow button or youtube subscribe button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you want to "generate" the click. Does not sound like you want to track (as you commented), but auto-click on it, which is definitely not allowed.

For tracking Facebook Social Plugins, the only possible and legal way is to use FB.Event.subscribe: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0